# Vertx/RxJava/WebClient/ApiGateway/Reactive

Tags: java, microservices, rx-java2, vert.x

I am working on **Apigateway** using **vert.x** and **RxJava**. I want to send reactive request for 2 `Api`s, get response from both of them and send combined JSON by `HttpServer`. But `onComplete()` executes to early and returns empty JSON. I think the problem arises from `asynchronous` character of the **vert.x** but I don't exactly what's wrong.

**Here is my method:**

```
private void dispatchBoth(RoutingContext routingContext) {

    Observer<String> observer = new Observer<String>() {

        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
            System.out.println("Start");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                if(s=="/api/userApi/selectAllUsers") {

                        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
                            client
                                .get(8081, "localhost", s)
                                .send(ar->{
                                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                                        HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();

                                        jsonArray.addAll(response.bodyAsJsonArray());
                                        System.out.println(jsonArray.encodePrettily());

                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                                    }
                                });

                }else if(s=="/api/holidayApi/selectAllHolidays") {
                        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
                        client
                                .get(8080, "localhost", s)
                                .send(ar -> {

                                    if (ar.succeeded()) {

                                        HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();

                                        jsonArray.addAll(response.bodyAsJsonArray());
                                       //  System.out.println(jsonArray.encodePrettily());

                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
                t.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println(jsonArray.encodePrettily());
                routingContext.response().end(jsonArray.encodePrettily());
        }
    };
    Observable.fromArray(com).subscribe(observer);
}
```

And that's the output I get on the console:

```
[ ]
[ {
  "holidayId" : 2,
  "userId" : 3,
  "place" : "Poland",
  "date" : {
    "year" : 2016,
    "month" : "DECEMBER",
    "dayOfMonth" : 29,
    "dayOfWeek" : "THURSDAY",
    "era" : "CE",
    "dayOfYear" : 364,
    "leapYear" : true,
    "monthValue" : 12,
    "chronology" : {
      "id" : "ISO",
      "calendarType" : "iso8601"
    }
  }
}, {
  "holidayId" : 10,
  "userId" : 1,
  "place" : "Netherland",
  "date" : {
    "year" : 2020,
    "month" : "JANUARY",
    "dayOfMonth" : 21,
    "dayOfWeek" : "TUESDAY",
    "era" : "CE",
    "dayOfYear" : 21,
    "leapYear" : true,
    "monthValue" : 1,
    "chronology" : {
      "id" : "ISO",
      "calendarType" : "iso8601"
    }
  }
}, {
  "userId" : 1,
  "name" : "Kacper",
  "phone_number" : "667667202"
}, {
  "userId" : 3,
  "name" : "Kamil",
  "phone_number" : "6734583443"
}, {
  "userId" : 4,
  "name" : "Janek",
  "phone_number" : "231253575"
}, {
  "userId" : 5,
  "name" : "Grzegorz",
  "phone_number" : "123456789"
}, {
  "userId" : 6,
  "name" : "Justin",
  "phone_number" : "111000111"
}, {
  "userId" : 8,
  "name" : "Mike",
  "phone_number" : "997"
}, {
  "userId" : 9,
  "name" : "Gorge",
  "phone_number" : "991"
} ]
```

Comment: I cannot see "onCompile" which executes too early.

Comment: Sorry I meant onComplite().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onComplete` executes on time: when the input flow of strings is finished. You need another way to wait the moment when all I/O operations are completed. This is a tricky part, I do not know if Vertx or RxJava can do this, but standard Java API can, using `CompletableFuture`.  So we create adapter from CompletableFuture to Handler, which holds the result of one I/O operation:

```
class HandelerFuture extends CompletableFuture<JsonArray> 
         implements Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponse<Buffer>>> {
    @Override
    public void handle(AsyncResult<HttpResponse<Buffer>> ar) {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            JsonArray array = ar.result().bodyAsJsonArray();
            super.complete(array);
        } else {
            super.completeExceptionally(ar.cause());
        }
    }
}
```

Besides, you need not to wrap the body of `onNext` method in a `Tread`. Second, you need not to check what the url string is passed, as it does not make any difference. Third, you use Observer only to handle a list of url strings - this is overcomplication. Plain loop is sufficient.

```
CompletableFuture<HandelerFuture[]> dispatchBoth(String... urls) {
    ArrayList<HandelerFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>(); // all results
    for (String url : urls) {
        HandelerFuture future = new HandelerFuture();
        futures.add(future);
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
        client.get(8081, "localhost", url)
              .send(future);
    }
    CompletableFuture all = new CompletableFuture();
    HandelerFuture[] array = futures.toArray(new HandelerFuture[0]);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(array)
            .thenRunAsync(() -> all.complete(array));
    return all;
}
```

then it can be run as follows:

```
    CompletableFuture<HandelerFuture[]> future = dispatchBoth(com);
    HandelerFuture[] results = future.get();
    JsonArray finalArray;
    for (HandelerFuture result:results) {
        try {
            // extract partial json array
            JsonArray partialArray = result.get();
            // combine partialArray with finalArray somehow
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // this is the exception got in handle() method as ar.cause().
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    routingContext.response().end(finalArray.encodePrettily());
```

You did not tell how you are going to combine json arrays, so I left this unimplemented.

Comment: Alright I understand now, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are starting a new thread in `onNext()`? When you start a new thread using `Thread.start()`, it will carry on its work in parallel and the current `Observable.onNext()` will consider the work complete. This will cause `onComplete()` to be called.

There is no one waiting for the thread's job  to be completed. Hope you see what I mean.

Now, I am not familiar with vert.x, but going by RxJava ways, there seems to be no need for the use of `Thread`. You may remove it and keep the rest of the logic directly in the `onNext()` method.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, but still after deleting `Thread` part,  `onComplite()` is executed before `onNext()`.